# Ill Formed XML Code

Tags: c#, xml, amazon-mws

I currently try updating product data with the Amazon MWS and the Feeds API. My problem: Updating the Inventory and setting a new quantity for my products resolves in errors like this:

```
The XML you submitted is ill-formed at the Amazon Envelope XML level
at (or near) line X, column Y.
```

On the other hand, I export nearly the same XML to update the prices. That works just fine...

Here is an example of the XML that i upload to the Feeds API to update the quantity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<AmazonEnvelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" noNamespaceSchemaLocation="amznenvelope.xsd">
  <Header>
    <DocumentVersion>1.01</DocumentVersion>
    <MerchantIdentifier>{SellerID}</MerchantIdentifier>
  </Header>
  <MessageType>Inventory</MessageType>
  <Message>
    <MessageID>1</MessageID>
    <Inventory>
      <SKU>ArtNoXX</SKU>
      <Quantity>10</Quantity>
    </Inventory>
  </Message>
  <Message>
    <MessageID>2</MessageID>
    <Inventory>
      <SKU>ArtNoXY</SKU>
      <Quantity>23</Quantity>
    </Inventory>
  </Message>
</AmazonEnvelope>
```

P.S.: I'm using C# and a XMLDocument to create the XML File...

Edit: The Error is shown multiple times. Only the first and the last 3 lines don't appear in the error log.

Example:

```
... (or near) line 10, column 16.
```

That would be

```
<Inventory>
```

Regarding to the column, it should be

```
>
```

Comment: "Ill-formed" is not the same as "ill formatted". Please show us a sample of the line that's causing a problem.

Comment: I updated the post with some additional information... Do you have any idea to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrong namespace in your config ?

Yours :
noNamespaceSchemaLocation="amznenvelope.xsd"

Should be:
noNamespaceSchemaLocation="amzn-envelope.xsd"

Comment: Close ;) I found the problem. It should be xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="amzn-envelope.xsd"